# Restricting a wallet to a specific destination address

Tags: wallet, address

I have an idea for a tool I'd like to build, but first I need to understand the Bitcoin protocol a little better.

Is there any way, hypothetically, to ensure that a given wallet or address can only transmit to a restricted address or set of addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol itself doesn't allow such a restriction but M of N functionality might be a way to implement something like this.

- [How will multisig addresses work?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6100/153)

Comment: Great, that might allow for a novel solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the private key you have full control over the relative address, there is no partial control.

If you want to achieve things like that, you have to keep the private key yourself, and let the users interact only through your interface, were obviously you can enforce any rule you like.

That said, you'd better state *what* you want to achieve, and now *how* you think you would need to do that.